# Sharing an Internet connection for Active Directory users through a domain controller?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

**Requirement:**

---

I have two [NICs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller) in my server ([DC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_controller)).

Frist NIC - WAN (static IP address)

Second NIC - LAN (static for [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) users to join)

I need to share the Internet connection from the first NIC to the second NIC.

How do I enable clients to access the Internet when they connect to the domain controller (Active Directory)?

---

Comment: Is the AD your Default Gateway?

Comment: What is the reason to do so? Why not set it up in a more conservative way with a separate router? It just is not a good idea to put more functionality on domain controllers.

Comment: You're using your domain controller as your Internet gateway? If you're worried that hackers on the internet are bored then you need to give them something that's actually a challenge, not just more of the same ol' 'too easy to bother with'.

Comment: You're just inviting problems trying to do this. Buy yourself a small firewall for a few hundred $ and do it properly. You'll save yourself money in the long run.

Comment: Stop. Back away from your Domain Controller. Hire someone that knows that they are doing.

Comment: I have succesfully share internet using 2 NIC after playing arround in registry and ICS

Comment: since it is not a good practice and safe i am going to have a dedicated system to share internet using RRAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do that, because you shouldn't expose your Domain Controller directly to the Internet.

Though, you can do that but keep in mind the right management of the Firewall.

You need two network cards on your domain controller, one to the LAN and another one to the Internet.

You should install the RRAS role on that server (with this your server will work as a router) and in RRAS enable the feature called NAT. This is really simple and there is a lot of documentation on the web.

You should change the gateway of all your machines to be the LAN network interface card of the Domain Controller. If you have a DHCP server, make the change on it.

Comment: +1 because RRAS is actually the way to do that; but it really shouldn't be done on a DC.

Comment: yes its not secure...

Answer (score 5):

NEVER MULTIHOME DOMAIN CONTROLLERS. It is not considered good practice. You should not do this especially if you are asking such elementary questions. The guy I replaced did this and I've had AD headaches because of this.

Use radius or a proxy to control internet access. Or a cheap router. Anything but this.